# How to create an unit test in runtime? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I am interesting in knowing how the [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) website run/execute the unit test which was written by users (externally)?

For example:

1. I create a task (inside the form field)
2. I create a unit test for that task (inside the form field)
3. Submit the form with unit test and task to the server
4. As a result, the task has been successfully published

After that some user opens my task:

1. This user creates a function to finish my task
2. Send form with that function to the server
3. The server receives the user's function as a string and executes my unit test on this function.
4. As a result, return the result of the function execution

The server received my unit test as a `string`, also the server received a user function as a `string`. So, the question is how this server parse/handle it and returns a result of it?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds to me like `eval`!

Comment: @alex-rokabilis Do you have any material about that? How to run a unit test using `eval`?